# Slider from Top

Tags: jquery, html, css

Something is going wrong with my images, I couldnt solve this problem. Here is my coding..

HTML

```
<div id="adsBox">
    <div id="ads"> <a href="#"> <img src="picture.jpg" alt="ads"> </a> </div>
    <p> <a href="#" id="showLink" class="showAds">HIDE</a> </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ads {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

#adsBox {
    text-align:right;
    color:black;
    width:970px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

#adsBox a {
    color:#535353;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#adsBox a:hover {
    color:#4682b4;
}

#ads a {
    margin:10px;
}

#showLink {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.hideLink {
    display:none;
}
```

I'm using jQuery to slide down. Everything is alright just the problem is image is not really on the div. It's a little bit moving to the right. Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/53VYP/). Any ideas?

Comment: can you add your jquery to the fiddler?

Comment: can you add a valid image and you script to the fiddle?

Comment: I tried to delete `text-align:right` but it's still the same. @Justin

Comment: @TilwinJoy hello, can you guide me how to add valid image there? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here.

```
#ads a {
    margin:10px;
}
```

The image inside div will move to the right a little bit because of margin left has 10 pixels. It has to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the width in pixels, as `width:970px;`

change it to

`width:100%;`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/53VYP/1/)

*side note: you might want to close the img tag, hope this fixes your problem*

Comment: That makes sense to me. I've solved this problem anyway, I've answered there. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @Anthosiast Well if you set width in pixels, it'll look fine in your screen, but it'll create a horizontal scroll in devices with smaller resolutions or in a jsfiddle. since your image in fiddle was broaken, this is the only thing that was visible.

Comment: Yeah it will be very useful for responsive. Thanks for letting me know.